# I can't start a new WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed in my computer but when I try to open a new WPF project, I can't find it. I only find the WIN Form project.
So does the VS 2008 not support WPF projects or what?

Comment: Have reinstalled/repaired VS ?

Comment: what is the edition of VS 2008 you have? Please also try to run `devenv.exe /setup` from the visual studio command prompt, and report if it solves the problem

Comment: All VS2008 editions should support WPF.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: not express (or at least, not all express editions)

Comment: The only one that doesn't is called WebDeveloper, not VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the .NET framework to at least 3.0. If you have it set to 2.0 or lower you will not have WPF available as a template.

[image]

I do not think that it should be needed, but you may want to install the latest version of .NET framework 3.5.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22

Answer (score 1):

VS 2008 support fully WPF project (according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)),